# Get the content of a row from sqlDataReader as a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a SqlDataReader reader, where I don't know the data structure in advance, i.e. the number of columns is unkown. I'd like to put the table in csv file.
I retrieve the columns from

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = reader.GetSchemaTable();
```

So I have them in dt.Columns() after it. Then, I want to do something like this:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    writer.WriteLine(string.Join(";",ListWithRowContent))
}
```

However, I have it hard to put the content of a row into ListWithRowContent list with something like linq .Select , but "reader"  object can't be queried.
Question: how to do it (please no for loop!)?

Comment: use `DataTable.AsEnumerable()`

Comment: using it I can query a DataTable object (dt), but I need to query a SqlDataReader object (reader) or something inside it.

Comment: DataReader has nothing inside it. That's why it is used in a loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming, that reader is positioned on any record:

```
var values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];

reader.GetValues(values);

writer.WriteLine(string.Join(";", values.Select(v => v.ToString())));
```

or more convenient way (FW 4.0 or higher):

```
var values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];

reader.GetValues(values);

writer.WriteLine(string.Join(";", values));
```

Comment: thanks you! just few remarks, I think "var values = ..." should be called before the reader is positioned on any record, i.e. before  "while(reader.Read())". Besides, I found out that string.Join requires an array and not a list (it's my fault), so it must be additionally .ToArray() at the end , i.e. "values.Select(v => v.ToString()).ToArray()"

Comment: @MaxLi, if you're using FW 3.5 or lower, then, yes - `.ToArray()` is a requirement.

Comment: Nice to know, I'm using FW 3.5. I thought that it's strange that it works only with arrays and not iterables